# Google Analytics detects conversions for old Mailchimp campaigns

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, mailchimp

We send emails through Mailchimp and have GA connected to track conversions (customer see's email, clicks product and purchases online).

However, I'm seeing lots of conversions and revenue in GA from old email campaigns.

[image: GA Campaign]
Take our black friday email for example. We sent this email on November 22 2022, yet on February 6 2023 GA is saying I had a conversion from this email for £713.13
I have found this order, and tracked the customers behaviour in Mailchimp. They opened the email once in November and **not **in February, so why is this being marked as a conversion from this email?

We use standard Mailchimp >< GA Integration, each email has a unique GTM_Campaign URL that we use to find the campaigns in Analytics.

It's impossible for us to accurately report email ROI with the above happening.
Any suggestions/fixes welcome.

I would expect to see conversions on the day we sent the email (and a short period after) but not 3-6 months later where users are not viewing the email again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, tracking opened emails only works when the user allows third party resources to be loaded into opened email. A lot of people don't allow that thing to happen, so it should be common for you to see clicks from emails with no opens.

It's completely ok for a user to open the email, allowing the open event to fire (for example, due to accessing it from web), then close it, then open it in two months, blocking the event from firing (because this time the user opens it somewhere safe, like in a mail client) and make a purchase from there. Moreover, it's normal for the users to open the email, go to the page, bookmark it for later and come back to it in a few months, still having all the email utm parameters in the url.

As per how you want to report on this, there are multiple ways to report. One good way to report it is to report on campaigns performance and email performance separately, not including late campaigns conversions in campaign reports, but include them in overall email marketing performance. The number of late conversions should be generally irrelevant. It should generally be at the level comparable to adblocker usage, so if you're ok to losing 5-10% of your conversions reporting to adblocker, then it should be ok for you to lose 2-5% of them to late conversions.